# Drools setting the rules sequence order

Tags: java, drools

I want to set the flow in which rules should be executed. I know that using rule-flow group we can set the sequence using eclipse-gui. But I want the solution without it and want to define it in drl file only.

Comment: You can try with `salience`. It set order in which rules will execute.

Answer (score 0):

Rule-flow groups and agenda groups are the same thing now, and you can easily control agenda groups, either from your Java application or by adding the API calls to (some of) your rules.

The "Expert" manual, Section 6.2.2.4., Agenda Groups contains the essentials.